# Facebook - Google analytics not capturing inner tab page events/page tracking

Tags: facebook, events, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

The issue is that I'm using Google Analytics to capture user events as the proceed through my application (sits within a tab). The landing page is working fine and data is being sent to GA but when I click on a link on the landing page that takes the user to a new page (still inside the tab) the event/page tracking isn't being captured by Google. I can see the image being requested in Firebug and the parameters are fine but I don't see any instances of it event or the page being tracked in my GA account.

**Simplified:** APP TAB: Default­.aspx (tracking working) --> link to Quiz.aspx which is still in the tab (tracking stops working).

Anyone else experiencing this? Any insight you could be provide would be appreciated.